# KIE Workbench - Alternate deployment instead of Maven?

Tags: drools, kie, kie-workbench

In new KIE Worbench, is it possible to build & deploy to a specific location instead of a maven-repo? The use case is, if we bundle this workbench for authoring drools rules part of our application & if maven is not supported in the deployed environment, what are the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone's reference -- this is not possible in current version of kie-workbench. See below post from drools-dev

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/AIPYpF_08wM